# How would you integrate an Angular 2 CLI frontend project with a Truffle 2 project?

Tags: truffle, gui

I'm using Angular 2, with TypeScript, Webpack and all that on my main projects, so every time I have to go back to a Truffle project using AngularJS 1.x, a kitten dies and my head hurts a little.

How would you integrate an Angular 2 CLI frontend project with a Truffle 2 project?

Comment: Here is a React based example project if web3 if that's any help: https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

I never use truffle 2, but this may help if you go to my project that I inegrate  Angular 2 and truffle 3  together at https://github.com/Ratimon/MyDWallet. After you npm install, It is important to go to

node_modules/ethjs-abi/internals/webpack/webpack.config.js:      and
node_modules/ethjs-util/internals/webpack/webpack.config.js:

then change  from loader: 'json'  to loader: 'json-loader'

Comment: That's interesting. Why do you have to do this modification in NPM modules directly? Not a very good solution given that these should be constant files.